# Nextjs invalid href passed to router

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I got an error:

```
Invalid href passed to next/router: /users//posts, repeated forward slashes (//) or backlashes \ are not valid in the href
```

I understand why this is happening

```js
handleClick = () => {
  // some code
  router.push(`/users/${userId}/posts`)
}
```

`userId` is asynchronousely fetched so it doesn't exist during the compilation causing `router.push('/users//posts')`. However, this code is inside `handleClick` which is triggered on button click.

How do i resolve this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with compilation, at runtime `userId` is empty, that is your error.

Comment: Could you provide the rest of the code where `userId` is declared/set?

Answer (score 2):

It actually wasn't about `router.push()` But my navbar. Problem was that my navbar's href was `/users/[userId]/posts` and `userId` wans't filled out

Answer (score 0):

```
handleClick = () => {
  // some code
  //check link you are pushing
  console.log(`/users/${userId}/posts`)
  //router.push(`/users/${userId}/posts`)
}
```

You can't have `//` in your link, debug the `{userId}`, think it's undefined, it's why error appears.

P.S. If `userId` is async, put `if condition` before `router.push`

Answer (score 0):

If `userId` is fetched asynchronously, then what the function and component which calls that function look like?

You have the `router.push` function in `handleClick` function, then I guess you need to pass a parameter for the `userId`.

```
<SomeComponent onClick={() => handleClick(userId)} />
```

And the function looks like:

```
const handleClick = (userId) => {
  router.push(`/users/${userId}/posts`);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

You should remove `/` it is between `users` and `${userId}`.

```
handleClick = () => {
  router.push(`/users${userId}/posts`)
}
```